# is this multi-label image classification result good?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multilabel-classification

I'm working on a multi label image classification problem which has 5 classes. i used a weighted version of cross entrypy, shown below. The classification report on test set is also shown below. i have the following questions. it would be very helpful is someone can answer them.

1) Is the loss function valid/good/correct for multi label image classification on imbalance dataset?

2) Does the classification report look good? for instance, for label 0,  i get low precision(0.06) and high recall(0.75), is it good? which evaluation metric should i pay most attention to, accuracy OR precision OR recall OR f1 score?

3) it seems that label 4 is well learned, while label 1,2,3 are bad. Why would this happen and what can i do to improve the result of label 1,2,3?

```
def loss_fn(y_true,y_pred):
    loss = 0

    loss -= (float(positive_weights[0]*y_true[0])*K.log(y_pred[0]) + float(negative_weights[0]*(1-y_true[0]))*K.log(1-y_pred[0]))
    loss -= (float(positive_weights[1]*y_true[1])*K.log(y_pred[1]) + float(negative_weights[1]*(1-y_true[1]))*K.log(1-y_pred[1]))
    loss -= (float(positive_weights[2]*y_true[2])*K.log(y_pred[2]) + float(negative_weights[2]*(1-y_true[2]))*K.log(1-y_pred[2]))
    loss -= (float(positive_weights[3]*y_true[3])*K.log(y_pred[3]) + float(negative_weights[3]*(1-y_true[3]))*K.log(1-y_pred[3]))
    loss -= (float(positive_weights[4]*y_true[4])*K.log(y_pred[4]) + float(negative_weights[4]*(1-y_true[4]))*K.log(1-y_pred[4]))
    loss = float(loss)
    return loss
```

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.06      0.75      0.11       347
       1       0.05      0.43      0.09       314
       2       0.05      0.42      0.08       286
       3       0.16      0.39      0.23      1017
       4       0.78      1.00      0.88      4867
```

```
   macro avg       0.22      0.60      0.28      6831
weighted avg       0.59      0.84      0.67      6831
 samples avg       0.38      0.87      0.50      6831
```

Comment: Hi, I think you would find better luck with this question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is entirely dependent on context -- what the labels represent, and what you are trying to do with the model --. To take an example, say you were predicting tumour presence from images, and label 2 corresponds to a tumour that has a fatality rate of 95% without treatment and label 4 corresponds to a tumour that has a survival rate of 99%. By having low scores on label 2, your model is practically unusable in a real-world context.

Comment: `positive_weights`, `K` and `negative_weights` are not defined.  what are these ?